# How to install Flash Builder 4 or a Flash Builder plugin on Eclipse in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, apache-flex, ubuntu, flex4, flash-builder

I want to install Flash Builder 4  or a Flash Builder plugin on Eclipse in Ubuntu. There are two methods I know to achieve it.

```
1. Use fb4linux.
2. Use wine and follow these steps 
   http://diariolinux.com/2009/06/22/how-to-install-flash-builder-on-linux/
```

Second method gave me errors while installing. First method is good and installs fine, however it doesn't have design mode. They say it isn't supported in linux. Is there a work around or some other plugin to enable it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fb4linux is a hack of the Flash Builder plugin. It won't have most of the useful features as its in breach of the license itself. I've tried the second route myself and also had problems.

One of my personal goals is to get it working on Ubuntu 9.10+ as that's what I use primarily. I have to go to Windows 7 to use FB currently.

**Disclosure:** Although I'm not an employee of Adobe, I do quite a bit of work with them: http://www.phparch.com/author/keith/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) instead of FB on Linux.  It has great Flex support.

Comment: No design View and designView plugin doesn't have all options

Comment: I never used design view anyhow.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same boat you are, but have learned that design mode in FB4 is a broken toy anyway.  See this:  http://flexonjava.blogspot.com/2010/04/enterprise-flex-development-dos-and.html

FB4Linux is definitely the way to go.  Works great.