# Eclipse flex plugin issue

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder

I've downloaded flex plugin for eclipse but my problem is I can't use, everytime that I try do something i have empty blank page, as shown in that picture. I tried add some components but no result. Any idea fix this problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Flash builder doesn't work very well on Linux. (It's not officially supported.) There are [some ways to get it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171598/how-to-install-flash-builder-4-or-a-flash-builder-plugin-on-eclipse-in-ubuntu-10) but things that depend on the licensing component, like design view, will probably be broken.

Personally, I think design mode is useless anyway. You're much better off writing the mxml yourself.

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried writing myself in mxml file but after runing I have also this problem (empty blank)