# How can one install the latest apache flex sdk on the eclipse IDE on linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, apache, apache-flex

Been searching on the web for days...

There are a lot of threads about install flex or Apache flex but never Apache flex 4.11 on eclipse in a Linux environment. I am looking to develop a flash website with completely open source tools that is why I am using such a platform. Any assistance you could provide would be much appreciated.

I have eclipse install under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I am not sure how to proceed. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I am reading more and more about dropping of linux support for this tool. I am still holding out hope for multi-platform development from linux but may need to go dual boot create my flash content in windows then move it to the linux.

Comment: Apache Flex is just an SDK--if you get the binary form it is just a bunch of SWC libraries.  I don't understand what you mean by "install Apache Flex on Eclipse".  If you want to build Apache Flex applications on Linux I believe you'll have to use command line tools. [or write your own ANT style compile Scripts].  I know Flash Builder does not work on Linux.  You could try FlashDevelop, but I Don't know if it is eclipse based.  You could try FDT but I don't know if it supports Linux.  I believe IntelliJ has Linux support, but it is not eclipse based.

Comment: @Reboog711 I know you can install various plug-ins into eclipse like the android sdk. I wanna do something similar to eclipse. Read of this being done in the past but its probably no longer an option. Do you have any advice, If i cannot do free whats the lowest cost option? I really would like to avoid pure command line if possible as I am not pro and it would really bog me down.

Comment: I think I already provided all the options I am aware of. My personal feeling is that Linux is not a good OS for developing Flash Platform applications because the most current runtimes are not supported; so it is difficult to test.

Comment: Though the SDK is opensource, there is only one IDE that supports Flex that is free (FlashDevelop) and it's Windows-only. FlashBuilder - even though it's an Eclipse plugin - does not run on Linux. Don't know about FDT. IntelliJ runs fine though. All of them are commercial, but you can get an opensource license for IntelliJ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Flash Builder 4 or a Flash Builder plugin on Eclipse in Ubuntu 10.04?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171598/how-to-install-flash-builder-4-or-a-flash-builder-plugin-on-eclipse-in-ubuntu-10)